# What does y, _ assignment do in python / sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

As a relative new-comer to Python I am trying to use the sklearn RandomForestClassifier. One example from a how-to guide by yhat is the following:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
df['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(df)) <= .75
df['species'] = pd.Factor(iris.target, iris.target_names)
df.head()

train, test = df[df['is_train']==True], df[df['is_train']==False]

features = df.columns[:4]
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=2)
y, _ = pd.factorize(train['species']) # assignment I don't understand
clf.fit(train[features], y)

preds = iris.target_names[clf.predict(test[features])]
pd.crosstab(test['species'], preds, rownames=['actual'], colnames=['preds'])
```

Can some explain what the y, _ assignment does and how it works. It isn't used explicitly, but  I get an error if I leave it out.

Comment: I need more understanding of the code. Is it just somehow coincidence that iris.target and y all match with iris.target_names? Since factorize() encodes the input value to categorical value and there is no guarantee it encodes the same way used as the mapping from iris.target to iris.target_names. For example 0 is mapped to setosa, but how it is guaranteed that factorize() does the same mapping when it encodes the values? Not sure if you understand my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You decompose the returned tuple into two distinct values, `y` and `_`.

`_` is convention for "I don't need that value anymore".

It's basically the same as:

```
y = pd.factorize(train['species'])[0]
```

with the exception that this code would work for any indexable return value with at least 1 element, while yours explicitly needs exactly two items in the returned value.

Comment: ... except that `[0]` would work if the return value had more than two elements, so using `y, _ =` is also a sanity check on `pd.factorize`'s output.

Comment: That's of course right, it would work if it had at least 1 element. I will add it.

Comment: Does anyone know the origin of the underscore convention?

Comment: @HansZauber In Prolog it's a variable that matches everything, so you don't care what the value of the match is. Maybe that's the origin?

Comment: thank you all: that clarifies it for me. Indeed Juri's equivalent works with the code, too.

Comment: I need more understanding of the code. Is it just somehow coincidence that `iris.target` and `y` all match with `iris.target_names`? Since `factorize` encode the input value to categorical value and there is no guarantee it encodes the way used same as the mapping from `iris.target` to `iris.target_names`. For example `0` is mapped to `setosa`, but how it is guaranteed that factorize() does the same mapping when it encodes the values? Not sure if you understand my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It means that `pd.factorize(train['species'])` is returning a tuple/list/generator/iterable of two items. In Python you can do

```
x, y = [1, 2]
```

and now `x == 1` and `y == 2`. In your case `y` becomes the first value and variable `_` the second. Underscore `_` is often used as a name for variable which is not going to be used.